# PHP Exec command - How to pass input to a series of questions

Tags: php, exec

I have a program on my linux server that asks the same series of questions each time it executes and then provides several lines of output.  My goal is to automate the input and output with a php script.

The program  is not designed to accept input on the command line.  Instead, the program asks question 1 and waits for an  answer from the keyboard, then the program asks question 2 and waits for an answer from the keyboard, etc.

I know how to capture the **output** in an array by writing:
$out = array();
exec("my/path/program",$out);

But how do I handle the **input**?
Assume the program asks 3 questions and valid answers are:  left  120  n
What is the easiest way using php to pass that input to the program?
Can I do it somehow on the exec line?

I’m not a php noob but simply have never needed to do this before.
Alas, my googling is going in circles.

Comment: Can you make it so your command line program takes the inputs through the command? Just take the PHP values then pass them as command line arguments.

Comment: It's a C++ program and I'm more of a php/javascript kinda guy.  While I do have the source code, I would prefer not to try and fiddle with  it if possible.

Comment: @user but why not do this the normal PHP way - have a form, submit it to a PHP script, exec() and output the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First up, just to let you know that you're trying to reinvent the wheel. What you're really looking for is [expect(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), which is a command-line utility intended to do exactly what you want without involving PHP.

However, if you really want to write your own PHP code you need to use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). Here are some good code examples on reading from STDOUT and writing to STDIN of the child process using `proc_open`:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#79665
- [How to pass variables as stdin into command line from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390604/how-to-pass-variables-as-stdin-into-command-line-from-php/2390755#2390755)
- http://camposer-techie.blogspot.com/2010/08/ejecutando-comandos-sobre-un-programa.html (this one is in Spanish, sorry, but the code is good)

Finally, there is also an [Expect PECL module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php) for PHP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip about expect(1).  I was unaware of that tool. Bad news - I'm using a shared host (Blue host) and their php was apparently not compiled with expect(1) support.  I'll explore proc_open.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the arguments to the exec line.

```
exec("/path/to/programname $arg1 $arg2 $arg3");
```

... but don't forget to apply [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) on every argument! Otherwise, you're vulnerable to injected malicious code.

Comment: Pekka - thanks for the suggestion.  I love simple, but it's not working for me.  To clarify:  The program (which  I did not write) asks several separate questions.  It expects a keyboard reply to each one.  Is this technique supposed to take the place of keyboard entry?

Comment: @user556597 - What your ask for is different from what you stated in the above comment, try update your question with relevant details

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = array();
//add elements/parameters/input to array
string $execpath = "my/path/program ";
foreach($out as $parameter) {
  $execpath += $parameter;
  //$execpath += "-"+$execpath; use this if you need to add a '-' in front of your parameters.
}
exec($execpath);
```