# How to remote shutdown computer with exec() php

Tags: php, exec

I want to remote shutdown computer that have same network with me, in cmd.exe we can execute this to do that

```
shutdown /m \\192.168.1.2 /s /f /c 'PC will shutdown in 5 seconds' /t 5
```

but i have tried with php command exec() and it didn't do anything. I put the php command in shutdown.php

```
exec("shutdown /m \\192.168.1.2 /s /f /c 'PC will shutdown in 5 seconds' /t 5");
```

Comment: Root privileges are needed.  Maybe add web user to sudoers and grant only that command.

Comment: I see  cmd.exe, are you trying to execute the command on a windows machine? edit: if yes, maybe try making a *.bat file to run to execute the command.

Comment: @AbraCadaver root privileges? i used windows 7 OS. The target computer has same administrator account with my computer so it can works in cmd.exe, but it can't works when it cames with exec()

Comment: @Odyssey1111 yes, on windows machine, thanks for suggestion. i will try it :D

Comment: Are you running the PHP on a webserver or on command line as administrator?

Comment: on xampp @Odyssey1111

Answer (score 0):

try this. in place of username, put administrator username and password. put the domain if exists. then put the name of bat file there. the bat file would contain the shutdown command. also try directly putting the command there.

```
runas /U username /P password /D Domain /E shutdown.bat
```

Researched from the community, found this helpful

> First up, just to let you know that you're trying to reinvent the
>   wheel. What you're really looking for is expect(1), which is a
>   command-line utility intended to do exactly what you want without
>   involving PHP.
>
> However, if you really want to write your own PHP code you need to use
>   proc_open. Here are some good code examples on reading from STDOUT and
>   writing to STDIN of the child process using proc_open:
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#79665 How to pass
>   variables as stdin into command line from PHP
>   http://camposer-techie.blogspot.com/2010/08/ejecutando-comandos-sobre-un-programa.html
>   (this one is in Spanish, sorry, but the code is good) Finally, there
>   is also an Expect PECL module for PHP.
>
> Hope this helps.

source : [PHP Exec command - How to pass input to a series of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550803/php-exec-command-how-to-pass-input-to-a-series-of-questions)

Comment: inside the exec("here !")

Comment: it doesnt work, but when i use system("runas.exe /user:administrator shutdown.bat"); it outputs text "Enter the password for administrator:", and how we can fill the password?

Comment: type it in when it asks for it :) additionally use the `savecred` attribute so it won't ask again and again.

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-application-as-run-as-administrator-from-the-command-prompt/12401075#comment79473988_12401075

Comment: it doesnt provide the input box that can fill the password.. i see your answer in other thread, and it still doesnt work

Comment: it wont provide the input box. it'll just ask in cli