# PDFTK with php://memory

Tags: php, pdftk

Question: Is it possible to use **php://memory** on a **exec** or **passthru** command?

I can use php variables in the exec or passthru with no problem, but I am having trouble with php://memory

background:

I am trying to eliminate all of my temporary pdf file writing with PDFTK.
1)I am writing an temporary fdf file
2) form-fill a temporary pdf file using #1
3) repeat #1 and #2 for all the pdfs
4) merge all pdf's together.

This currently works - but it creates a lot of files, and is the bottleneck.

I would like to speed things up with pdftk by making use of the virtual file php://memory

**First, I am trying to just virtualize the fdf file used in #1. 
Answering this alone is enough for a 'correct answer'.    :)**

The code is as follows:

```
$fdf = 'fdf file contents here';
$tempFdfVirtual= fopen("php://memory", 'r+');
if(  $tempFdfVirtual ) {
  fwrite(  $tempFdfVirtual, $fdf);
} else {
    echo "Failure to open temporary fdf file";
    exit;
}
rewind( $tempFdfVirtual);
$url = "unfilled.pdf";
$temppdf_fn = "output.pdf"; 
$command = "pdftk $url fill_form  $tempFdfVirtual output $temppdf_fn flatten"; 
$error="";   
exec( $command, $error );
if ($error!="") {
    $_SESSION['err'] = $error;       
} else {
    $_SESSION['err'] = 0;
}
```

I am getting an errorcode #1.  If I do a stream_get_contents($tempFdfVirtual), it shows the contents.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Just an fyi to others that may be searching for the same thing... I used the answers provided below to get step# 1 done. I was then able to accomplish steps 2-4 using a combination of pdftk outputting to a pipe, and then ZendPdf to merge all the output streams to one pdf.  PDFTK is limited in accepting one virtual stream on merging virtual pdfs, but works fine for a list of actual files. The nice thing about ZendPdf is that you can pass it pdf data instead of the whole file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php://memory` and `php://temp` (and in fact any file descriptor) are only available to the currently-running php process. Besides, `$tempFdfVirtual` is a resource handle so it makes no sense to put it in a string.

You should pass the data from your resource handle to the process through its standard-in. You can do this with [`proc-open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which gives you more control over input and output to the child process than `exec`.

Note that for some reason, you can't pass a 'php://memory' file descriptor to a process. PHP will complain:

> Warning: proc_open(): cannot represent a stream of type MEMORY as a File Descriptor

Use `php://temp` instead, which is supposed to be exactly the same except it will use a temporary file once the stream gets big enough.

This is a tested example that illustrates the general pattern of code that uses `proc_open()`. This should be wrapped up in a function or other abstraction:

```php
$testinput = "THIS IS A TEST STRING\n";

$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($fp, $testinput);
rewind($fp);

$cmd = 'cat';
$dspec = array(
    0 => $fp,
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
);
$pp = proc_open($cmd, $dspec, $pipes);

// busywait until process is finished running.
do {
    usleep(10000);
    $stat = proc_get_status($pp);
} while($stat and $stat['running']);

if ($stat['exitcode']===0) {
    // index in $pipes will match index in $dspec
    // note only descriptors created by proc_open will be in $pipes
    // i.e. $dspec indexes with an array value.
    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    if ($output == $testinput) {
        echo "TEST PASSED!!";
    } else {
        echo "TEST FAILED!! Output does not match input.";
    }
} else {
    echo "TEST FAILED!! Process has non-zero exit status.";
}

// cleanup
// close pipes first, THEN close process handle.
foreach ($pipes as $pipe) {
    fclose($pipe);
}
// Only file descriptors created by proc_open() will be in $pipes.
// We still need to close file descriptors we created ourselves and
// passed to it.
// We can do this before or after proc_close().
fclose($fp);
proc_close($pp);
```

Untested Example specific to your use of PDFTK:

```
// Command takes input from STDIN
$command = "pdftk unfilled.pdf fill_form - output tempfile.pdf flatten"; 
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => $tempFdfVirtual, // feed stdin of process from this file descriptor
//    1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // Note you can also grab stdout from a pipe, no need for temp file
);
$prochandle = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
// busy-wait until it finishes running
do {
    usleep(10000);
    $stat = proc_get_status($prochandle);
} while ($stat and $stat['running']);

if ($stat['exitcode']===0) {
    // ran successfully
    // output is in that filename
    // or in the file handle in $pipes if you told the command to write to stdout.
}

// cleanup
foreach ($pipes as $pipe) {
   fclose($pipe);
}
proc_close($prochandle);
```

Comment: I am new to proc_open, so please bear with me. When I pass the virtualfdf file created via php://memory into proc_open, I am getting  proc_open() [<a href='function.proc-open'>function.proc-open</a>]: cannot represent a stream of type MEMORY as a File Descriptor.   If I have a variable $fdf containing a string - should I create a virtual file using stdout, or how should I pass that "file" into the proc_open properly?

Comment: I've since tried $tempFdfVirtual = fopen("php://stdout", 'r+');

Comment: Ahh, that is a serious bummer. This is a php limitation. Use `php://temp` instead of `php://memory`--it appears to work on my system, although I don't see why there should be a difference.

Comment: It works! I tried the php://temp as suggested.  Wow... I also found similiar code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390604/how-to-pass-variables-as-stdin-into-command-line-from-php   but noticed you did not need to do something similiar to fwrite($pipes[0], stream_get_contents(STDIN));

Comment: You could add `0 => array('pipe', 'w')` to the descriptor spec, and then `stream_copy_to_stream($tempFdfVirtual, $pipes[0])`. That is essentially what you are describing. But it's not really necessary here.

Comment: Thank you. Thinking forward: According to the pdftk docs:  Use - to pass a single PDF into pdftk via stdin .  On the cat command , I would have several pdf's. Would I simply use multiple dashes, and set up a stream for each one?

Comment: No, there's only one STDIN per process. You would need to create temporary files [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) and [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) and pass the filenames in the command line. However, the [docs for PDFTK `fill_form`](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-fill-form) seem to suggest that you can't have several input files anyway. You would need to rerun the process for each input+form combo.

Comment: If it helps you think of this, using STDIN and the `-` option with PDFTK is exactly like using pipes on the command line: `cat file.txt | command` or `command < file.txt`. You can't do that with multiple files unless it's meaningful to combine them with `cat`.

Comment: The fillform will only be with a single pdf. I am referring to steps 2-4 listed above in creating the pdf's virtually. Instead of a string of file names, in the final cat operation, I am going to try using pipes.

Comment: Ah. I highly doubt you can do input with a pipe, but you can try on the command line with `cat 1.pdf 2.pdf | pdftk - cat output - > output.pdf`. You can grab output from STDOUT though without a problem. If you use `tempnam()` as described above you should have an easier time preparing the input filenames.

Comment: 1) I noticed it was getting stuck in the do while loop when I had it output to a pipe. 2) When using a string of actual pdf files to merge, it's been no problem with tempnam(), but that is what I am trying to eliminate. Merging the virtual pdfs seems to be problem-child.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just that you're using `php://memory`, it's any file handle. File handles only exist for the current process. For all intents and purposes, the handle you get back from fopen cannot be transferred to any other place outside of your script.

As long as you're working with an outside application, you're pretty much stuck using temporary files. Your only other option is to try and pass the data to pdftk on stdin, and retrieve the output on stdout (if it supports that). As far as I know the only way to invoke an external process with that kind of access to its descriptors (stdin/stdout) is using the `proc_` family of functions, specifically [proc_open](https://www.php.net/proc_open).

Comment: Thank you - your quick response pointed me in a different direction yesterday, and sent me reading up on proc_open.