# PHP passing shell commands over SSH with special characters

Tags: php, bash, shell, special-characters

I am passing dynamic shell commands over SSH to servers with `PHP` using the `ssh2` library. The command I am passing is (note this is just an example, the commands are dynamic and user generated).

```
$command = 'ls -al
free -m';
```

Notice the newline, this is required, since users can type full bash scripts with newlines and tabs. Then, I do the following to build the actual command to execute with the ssh2 library:

```
$command = str_replace("'", "\'", $command);
$command = 'echo $\'' . $command . '\' | bash';
```

Which results in the final command of:

```
echo $'ls -al
free -m' | bash
```

The above command executes fine at the shell directly, but when I execute it from PHP using ssh2, and I getting:

```
ls: invalid option --  
Try `ls --help' for more information.
```

So I thought, ok there must be some special characters or the dollar sign is not being escaped, so I did:

```
  print_r(bin2hex($command));
```

Which results in:

```
 6563686f2024276c73202d616c0d0a66726565202d6d27207c2062617368
```

Converting the hex into ascii returns the correct command (exactly as above) though.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

That error comes from bash, not PHP.

When I try your command in a shell I get the same error.

But why are you using such a convoluted way of running bash?

Instead use `proc_open()`, with `bash` as the command, then feed it the user input in the stdin filehandle.

If you need an example of how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390755/664364

PS. I hope you know what you are doing allowing users to run arbitrary commands as the webserver user!

Comment: It is a long story to explain why it is setup like this. Security aside. Really, when you copy and paste the contents of `$command` you get a bash error? I don't in CentOS.

Comment: I do, yes. Although the error is different. I get `ls: invalid option -- 'e'`

Comment: I have edited the posted, please read the top to see a better explanation.

Comment: @Justin Your edit didn't change anything - I still think this is a bash error, and not a PHP one. Try using proc_open instead. Test it! Add a semicolon after the ls and watch it work.