# PHP passing values to command line: unable to read first line of output

Tags: php, python, command-line, stdout, stdin

I have the following code to run a `Python` script from `PHP` and pass inputs values to `stdin`. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390604/how-to-pass-variables-as-stdin-into-command-line-from-php))

```
$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
        1 => array("pipe", "w")
    );  
    $process = proc_open('python script.py', $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null); 
    if (is_resource($process)) {
        fwrite($pipes[0], "first input"); // input 1            
        fwrite($pipes[0], "second input"); // input 2

        fclose($pipes[0]); // has to be closed before reading output!
        fgets($pipes[1]); 
        $output = "";
        while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
            $output .= fgets($pipes[1]) . "</br>";
        }
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        proc_close($process);  
        echo $output;
    }
```

Problem: `$output` captures everything except the first line of `stdout` on the command line. For example, if the `Python` program prints `Hello`, `from`, `Python` is successive lines, `$output` only contains `from` and `Python`. How do I capture the first line of `stdout` too?

Comment: What do you think `fgets($pipes[1]); ` in line 11 does?

Comment: Wow! I had used `fgets($pipes[1]);` in line 11 to avoid reading the initial prompts for input into `$output'. Turns out that contained the first line of the actual output as well. Thanks!