# PHP exec waits for return key

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am trying to execute ffmpeg on PHP using exec, shell_exec, command and proc_open and did not manage to get any to work.
This is my command:

```
exec("ffmeg -I test.fvl output.mp4 2>&1", $output, $retval);
```

when I run this php command, the error happens when there's a duplicate output file and prompt a stderr asking if we want to overwrite it thus, waiting for a user input.
Is there any way around this to ignore the stderr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options, choose one that suits you the best:

- Avoid usage of duplicate file name: Check if the file name exists, if so then select different name `file_exists($output);` [PHP file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)
- Reuse the file name: Force the file to be overwritten `ffmeg -y` [ffmpeg Documentation 5.4 Main options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options)

Answer (score 0):

you can add the "-y" Parameter to overwrite the existing file.
Hope this helps.

Grtngs
Dustin

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#79665) ? Here's a [`sample code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390604/how-to-pass-variables-as-stdin-into-command-line-from-php/2390755#2390755) from another thread.

Edit: Knowing ffmeg, you can also add -y option in ffmpeg.

Comment: I did try proc_open to try to return a input to the prompt but it does not seem to be able to get the std_err value thus, unable to know when there is a duplicate from just the proc_open. However, it does work if I have known beforehand that it has a duplicate copy and write to stdin immediately.

Comment: If you don't mind overwriting the file, then you can add the -y option.