# How to use pdftk (as ubuntu snap) from php?

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdftk

**The short :**
I am trying to make this work :

```
$blank_pdf_form = "blankform.pdf";
$cmd = "pdftk $blank_pdf_form fill_form - output -";

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("pipe", "w")

);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {

    //row2xfdf is made-up function that turns HTML-form data to XFDF
    fwrite($pipes[0], raw2xfdf($_POST));
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $pdf_content = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.pdf"');
    echo $pdf_content;
}
```

Happily stolen here :[How to pass variables as stdin into command line from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390604/how-to-pass-variables-as-stdin-into-command-line-from-php)

**My issue**

It doesn't work with following message :

```
Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. 
See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
```

**My understanding :**

I am on ubuntu, pdftk is provided as a snap hence has very restricted access to the filesystem. Running from php (user `www-data`) restricts this even more.

**What I did/try :**

First errors were asking for directories to exist `/var/www/snap/pdftk/...` 
I created all of them manually granting `777`. Nothing changed.
I created a `tmp` folder with `777` in `/media` and performed `snap connect pdftk:removable-media :removable-media`.
php can access files when they are there. But still the same error with pdftk.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Where should the pdf be to be usable by pdftk ? 
I was thinking of using multiple pipes 1 for the pdf and 1 (x)fdf bu can't find whether it can be done or not?

Comment: Is there any reason why you must use a snap instead of a normal package?

Comment: Due to what I saw (and experienced), it is not anymore in the standard package repository of ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS).

Comment: Right. There is a replacement in newer versions of Ubuntu (18.10 onwards), and if you want to run on a stable version and are not on a hurry you can even wait for 20.04. If that is not an option, maybe https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/issues/150 can help. Disclaimer: I am the main author of that replacement.

Answer (score 0):

faced with such problem too.

Resolved it with changing home directory for www-data user to /home/www and now it's working well